# Setting the git describe as a shell variable

Tags: windows, git, shell, command-line

I'd like to create a directory based on the output of the `git describe` command.

This does **not** work:

```
set NAME = git describe
mkdir %NAME%
```

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Windows, to capture the output of a command, you use the `FOR /F` command.

Read `HELP FOR` and then try this

```
 FOR /F %a in ('git describe') do md %a
```

Comment: This looks like it solves the problem. I'm curious tough, if one used _Eval_, would it work?

Like `set NAME = Eval(git describe)`.
Unfortunately I'm not with my windows machine up so I can't test it right now. Anyway, just curious. Thanks!
-- reference: http://ss64.com/vb/eval.html

Comment: Eval is a VB function, it is not a Windows Command, so it cannot be executed in the windows command line.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, you could try the method that [PA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16198056/1737938) described.

Now if you're on Linux, the following might work:

Try this:

```
# Create the command
alias your-command="mkdir $(git describe)"

# Run the command
your-command
```

A folder with named with the output of `git describe` should be created.

This was tested on an ubuntu installation *and* it'll only work from inside the repository folder itself.

Note that the command described creates an *alias*. If you want to set the *output of `git describe` as a shell variable*, you should do the following:

```
# Create a local variable
foo=$(git describe)

# Create a new folder using `mkdir`
mkdir ${foo}
```

Note that now you have a local variable with the value of `git describe`. You can try:

```
echo ${foo}
```

Comment: You're right, didn't notice the tag. Edited for clarification!